# how to check all available rooms between start and end date?

Tags: mysql

my default available room(avaroom) is 0 . i want to check it avaiable or not when we select the start date and end date.

my sql query

```
select *
from roomcalendar
where day between '2016-08-26' and '2016-08-31' and avaroom != 0
```

The result will be like this.

[image]

I use this query

```
select *
from roomcalendar
where day between '2016-08-26' and '2016-08-31' and avaroom != 0  
having count(*) = datediff('2016-08-31', '2016-08-26')
```

result will be empty. it is true. because i check all the room are available or not between start and end date.

Next query I change to start date 26 and end date 27

```
select *
from roomcalendar
where day between '2016-08-26' and '2016-08-27' and avaroom != 0 
having count(*) = datediff('2016-08-27','2016-08-26')
```

Output will be 1 row

Yes.it still right. because 26 day room is available.

again i check start date 26 and end date 28.

```
select *
from roomcalendar
where day between '2016-08-26' and '2016-08-28' and avaroom != 0
having count(*) = datediff('2016-08-28','2016-08-26')
```

Yes.it still work.i think it empty because 28 room are not available.it also right.

Now. i try to change again. start date 29 and end date 30

```
select *
from roomcalendar
where day between '2016-08-29' and '2016-08-30' and avaroom != 0 
having count(*) = datediff('2016-08-30', '2016-08-29')
```

Opps! it show no result. i think 29 date room are available. it will be show the 1 row. right?
So how to get the right query?

another check again. start date 29 and end date 31.may be it will be show 2 result.

```
select *
from roomcalendar
where day between '2016-08-29' and '2016-08-31' and avaroom != 0 
having count(*) = datediff('2016-08-31','2016-08-29')
```

but it show only one result.

how to make the right query to pass all test?

Thanks.

Comment: why are you adding ` having count(*) = datediff('2016-08-31','2016-08-29')`?  this will only work when the result of your datediff() is the same as the number of returned rows -- in your example, when you query for a single day range and return a single row.  try omitting that entire part of the query!

Comment: @derelict yes bro. someone give me to solve the problem.but it not working. any idea for new query for my requirement. Thanks

Comment: @MinKoKo: what you exactly want as a output? Total No. of rooms available between selected dates or available No. of rooms with dates between selected dates?

Comment: @KrutiPatel i want to show the result room are available or not between two date.need to check room are 0 between start and end date.

Comment: @MinKoKo: Then you just need to remove `avaroom != 0` condition from your first query.

Comment: @KrutiPatel i make default avaible room is value 0. may be day 28 room is not avaiable(0). i start search between 26 to 29 .it will be no room output. right? if i remove it show all the result. i think it may be empty

Comment: @MinKoKo: There are rooms available on 26th and 29th. what you want?

Answer (score 0):

i see what you're going for

you need a row with avaroom > 0 for *every day* between start and end to be able to book a trip.

try:

```
having count(*) = datediff('start-date','end-date')+1
```

for datediff of 1 we expect 2 available days
for datediff of 4 we expect 5 available days

consider, trip starts 2016-09-01 and ends 2016-09-02 -- datediff is 1 but we need avaroom for 09-01 and 09-02, 2 days means 2 rows, so count(*) should be datediff + 1.

*note:* if you do not need to check departure date, you're going to want to use this same query but make sure you search with the end date being *one day before* departure date.  you can do this with mysql's `DATE_SUB('some-date',INTERVAL 1 DAY)` in place of the departure date `some-date`.

good luck!

Comment: it will be show 1 result. select * from roomcalendar where day between '2016-08-26' and '2016-08-27' and avaroom != 0 having count(*) = datediff('2016-08-26','2016-08-27')+1 but it show empty.

Comment: @MinKoKo: As there is no room available on 27th :)

Comment: @KrutiPatel departure date is need to check available room or not?

Comment: @MinKoKo: Depends on Requirement and Departure time.

Comment: @MinKoKo - added a note about if you don't need to check departure date to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

derelict got it right, but there is 1 more problem.
You need to use some counter to fill the gaps of inexistent dates.
This query will do the job.

```
select *,IF(avaroom != 0,1,0) a from roomcalendar where day between '2016-08-29' and '2016-08-30' GROUP BY a having sum(a) = datediff('2016-08-30','2016-08-29')+1
```